# ifelse with three conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, data-manipulation, lubridate

I have a data like this:

```
DT = data.table(Brand = c('Apple', 'Apple'),
                Time1 = c('2015-11', '2016-01'),
                value1 = c(119.7268, 336.8033),
                vaule2 = c(3380, 7710))
```

I want to generate new data like following:

```
Brand    Time1         Time2        LapseMonth     value1      value2
Apple    2015-11-01    2015-11-01       0          119.7268    3380
Apple    2015-11-01    2015-12-01       1          286.2842    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-01-01       2          286.2842    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-02-01       3          267.8142    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-03-01       4          286.2842    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-04-01       5          277.0492    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-05-01       6          286.2842    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-06-01       7          277.0492    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-07-01       8          286.2842    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-08-01       9          286.2842    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-09-01       10         277.0492    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-10-01       11         286.2842    0
Apple    2015-11-01    2016-11-01       12         157.3224    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-01-01       0          336.8033    7710
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-02-01       1          610.9016    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-03-01       2          653.0328    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-04-01       3          631.9672    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-05-01       4          653.0328    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-06-01       5          631.9672    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-07-01       6          653.0328    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-08-01       7          653.0328    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-09-01       8          631.9672    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-10-01       9          653.0328    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-11-01       10         631.9672    0
Apple    2016-01-01    2016-12-01       11         653.0328    0
```

I explain the new data here:
1. I will generate 2 new columns(`Time2` & `LapseMonth`)
2. I calculate the `value1`
3. The most important thing is:
   If `Time1` is **2015** and `LapseMonth` is **12**, `value1 = value2 * days_in_month(Time2) / 366` - original value1.
   See above, 157.3224 = 3380 * 30 / 366 - 119.7268.

Here is my code:

```
DT[ , Time1 := as.Date(paste(Time1, 01, sep = "-"), "%Y/%m/%d")]
DT[ , rep := ifelse(year(Time1)==2016, 12-month(Time1)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,rep)]
DT[ , LapseMonth := seq_len(.N)-1, by = Brand,Time1,value2) ]
DT[ , Time2:= Time1 - days(mday(Time1)-1) + months(LapseMonth)]
DT[ , value1 := ifelse(Time1==Time2,value1,value2*days_in_month(Time2)/366)]
DT[ , value2 := ifelse(Time1==Time2,value2,0)]
```

I don't know how to use `ifelse` to do `value1` when `Time1` is **2015** & `LapseMonth` is **12**.
Any idea?

```
DT[ , value1:=if(Time1==Time2 & LapseMonth==12) value2*days_in_month(time2)/366-value1]
```

However, I got some warnings:

```
Warning message:
In if (PurshasedDate == EXPMTH & LapseMonth == 12) WP * days_in_month(EXPMTH)/366 -  :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You can avoid `ifelse` in `data.table` i..e `data[Time1== 2015 & LapseMonth==12, value1 := value2 *days_in_month(Time2)/366 - value1]`

Comment: Why does `LapseMonth` go to 11 one time but 12 the other

Comment: I've cleaned up your attempt a bit. `DT = DT[ , V := f(...)]` is not proper `data.table` syntax as it creates unnecessary copies -- `DT[ , V := f(...)]` has already added the column to your table. Make sure you've gone through the [Getting Started vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I set the last month is 2016-12 and want the maximum of `Lapsemonth` = 12. Thus, 2016-01 just lapse to 11(12-1=11).

Comment: How is Time1 Nov 1 / Time 2 Dec 1 equal 286? 3380*31/366-119.7268 is about 167.

Comment: @akrun the result is not true.

Comment: @PeterChen  I think there are some doubts based on Michael's comments

Comment: @MichaelChirico 157.3224 = 3380 * 30 / 366 - 119.7268.

Comment: Yes, but you have 286 in your example.

Comment: Take `Apple    2015-11-01    2015-12-01       1          286.2842    0` as an eample.(row 2) 286.2842 = 3380 * 31/366. Because Dec has 31 days

Comment: What happened to subtracting 119.7268?

Comment: Also see `Apple    2015-11-01    2016-01-01       2          286.2842    0`. 286.2842 = 3380 * 31/366. Because 2016 Jan has 31 days.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I cannot understand what u mean. When `Time1` is 2015 & `LapseMonth` is 12, it is a special case. 157.3224 = 277.0492 - 119.7268. And 119.7268 is in original data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure out by myself and I post the answer here. Maybe other users have similar question in the future.

```
DT = data.table(Brand = c('Apple', 'Apple'),
            Time1 = c('2015-11', '2016-01'),
            value1 = c(119.7268, 336.8033),
            value2 = c(3380, 7710))
DT$Time1 <- ymd( paste( DT$Time1, 01, sep = "-"))
DT<-as.data.table(DT)
DT <-DT[,Time1:=as.Date(Time1,"%Y/%m/%d")]
DT <- DT[,rep := ifelse(year(Time1)==2016, 12-month(Time1)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,rep)]
DT <- DT[, LapseMonth := seq_len(.N)-1, by =. (Brand,Time1,value2) ]
DT <- DT[, Time2:= Time1 - days(mday(Time1)-1) + months(LapseMonth)]
DT <- DT[, value1 := ifelse(Time1==Time2,value1,ifelse(LapseMonth==12, value2*days_in_month(Time2)/366-value1, value2*days_in_month(Time2)/366))] 
DT <- DT[, value2 := ifelse(Time1==Time2,value2,0)]
```

Therefore, I get the result.

Comment: Don't do `DT <- DT` when using `:=`. Also, you defined `DT$Time1` twice (which made it obvious you don't need `ymd`. btw, there is `as.IDate` in data.table). Also, what's the point of `DT<-as.data.table(DT)`? It is already a data.table. Also, if it was a data.frame you could convert it in place to a data.table using `setDT`. Finally, these `ifelse` statement are very bad and you should just operate on subsets, e.g., `DT[Time1 == Time2, value1 := ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't understand the mapping of input to output, but whatever. Your main hangup is how to condition on the number of days in the month using `ifelse`. The answer is: don't.

Instead, just use a lookup table to get the number of days directly:

```
monthdays = data.table(month = sprintf('%02d', 1:12),
                       ndays = c(31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 
                                 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31),
                       key = 'month')

DT[ , {
  Time2 = seq.Date(Time1, as.Date('2016-12-01'), by = 'month')
  Time2 = Time2[seq_len(min(13L, length(Time2)))]
  LapseMonth = seq_along(Time2) - 1L
  value1 = value2*monthdays[format(Time2, '%m'), ndays]/366 - value1
  .(Brand = Brand, Time2 = Time2,
    LapseMonth = LapseMonth,
    value1 = value1,
    value2 = c(value2, rep(0, length(LapseMonth) - 1)))
  }, by = Time1]
#          Time1 Brand      Time2 LapseMonth   value1 value2
#  1: 2015-11-01 Apple 2015-11-01          0 157.3224   3380
#  2: 2015-11-01 Apple 2015-12-01          1 166.5574      0
#  3: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-01-01          2 166.5574      0
#  4: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-02-01          3 148.0874      0
#  5: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-03-01          4 166.5574      0
#  6: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-04-01          5 157.3224      0
#  7: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-05-01          6 166.5574      0
#  8: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-06-01          7 157.3224      0
#  9: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-07-01          8 166.5574      0
# 10: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-08-01          9 166.5574      0
# 11: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-09-01         10 157.3224      0
# 12: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-10-01         11 166.5574      0
# 13: 2015-11-01 Apple 2016-11-01         12 157.3224      0
# 14: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-01-01          0 316.2295   7710
# 15: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-02-01          1 274.0983      0
# 16: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-03-01          2 316.2295      0
# 17: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-04-01          3 295.1639      0
# 18: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-05-01          4 316.2295      0
# 19: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-06-01          5 295.1639      0
# 20: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-07-01          6 316.2295      0
# 21: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-08-01          7 316.2295      0
# 22: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-09-01          8 295.1639      0
# 23: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-10-01          9 316.2295      0
# 24: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-11-01         10 295.1639      0
# 25: 2016-01-01 Apple 2016-12-01         11 316.2295      0
#          Time1 Brand      Time2 LapseMonth   value1 value2
```

Comment: your answer is good. However, you can execute my code first. And row 13 looks like `Apple    2015-11-01    2016-11-01       12         277.0492    0` rather than `Apple    2015-11-01    2016-11-01       12         157.3224    0`.

Comment: What I want is change 277.0492 to 157.3224. Thanks

Comment: The lookup table should probably just have dates/idates (with the first day of the month) as a key rather than some string month. Feb doesn't always have 29 days, for one thing. Also, with dates, then you can roll-join onto them. If you have a sequence of months, then `shift(mday(x-1), type="lead")` or similar will give # days, I guess.